# Error: "This ZIP Format is not supported" when running MobSF

Tags: android, sast, mobsf

When I run MobSF over my android source code I get the error:

```
[ERROR] 22/Aug/2023 17:57:59 - This ZIP Format is not supported
[ERROR] 22/Aug/2023 17:57:59 - Internal Server Error: /api/v1/scan
[FATA] [MobSF] [2023-08-22T17:57:59Z] [/go/src/app/main.go:29] ▶ scan failed: scan responded with unexpected status code (500): {"error": "This ZIP Format is not supported"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it decides what is a valid android project: https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/blob/c2993d194487cdfcd14a58aba59c380b6416a779/mobsf/StaticAnalyzer/views/android/static_analyzer.py#L473-L488

```
def is_android_source(app_dir):
    """Detect Android Source and IDE Type."""
    # Eclipse
    man = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(app_dir, 'AndroidManifest.xml'))
    src = os.path.exists(os.path.join(app_dir, 'src/'))
    if man and src:
        return 'eclipse', True
    # Studio
    man = os.path.isfile(
        os.path.join(app_dir, 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'),
    )
    java = os.path.exists(os.path.join(app_dir, 'app/src/main/java/'))
    kotlin = os.path.exists(os.path.join(app_dir, 'app/src/main/kotlin/'))
    if man and (java or kotlin):
        return 'studio', True
    return None, False
```